# How to make sure my input stream is closed on activity exit (Android)?

Tags: android, inputstream

When my activity is created, I start up a thread which starts listening for keypad presses continuously `(while(true))` ... This works perfectly, however when I click back the input stream isn't closed and the next time I open that activity response is sporadic and unreliable.

MY CODE

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_keypad_test_button);

    // Set the view pager for return
    MainActivity.ViewPagerPosition = 1;

    // These are text views that turn green when the corrosponding key is pressed
    key0 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.btn_keypad_0);
    key1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.btn_keypad_1);
    key2 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.btn_keypad_2);
    key3 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.btn_keypad_3);
    key4 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.btn_keypad_4);
    key5 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.btn_keypad_5);
    key6 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.btn_keypad_6);
    key7 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.btn_keypad_7);
    key8 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.btn_keypad_8);
    key9 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.btn_keypad_9);
    keyClear = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.btn_keypad_clear);
    keyEnter = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.btn_keypad_enter);
    keyF1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.btn_keypad_f1);
    keyF2 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.btn_keypad_f2);
    keyF3 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.btn_keypad_f3);
    keyF4 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.btn_keypad_f4);
    keyF5 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.btn_keypad_f5);
    keyF6 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.btn_keypad_f6);
    keyF7 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.btn_keypad_f7);
    keyF8 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.btn_keypad_f8);

    // This is for later checking to see if all keys have been pressed at some point
    allKeys = new TextView[] { key0, key1, key2, key3, key4, key5, key6, key7, key8, key9,
            keyClear, keyEnter, keyF1, keyF2, keyF3, keyF4, keyF5, keyF6, keyF7, keyF8 };

    // I eventually set whether all keys have been pressed by looking at their tags
    for (TextView button : allKeys) {
        button.setTag(0);
    }

    // I use this method to create a rest api to work with my hardware keypad
    createRestAPI();

    clockUserAPI.getKeyboardStream().enqueue(new Callback<ResponseBody>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<ResponseBody> call, final Response<ResponseBody> response) {

            if (response == null) Log.v(TAG, "Null response");

            else {

                Log.v(TAG, "About to start thread");
                Thread keyboardInputThread = new Thread(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {

                        running = true;

                        InputStream inputStream = null;
                        try {
                            // THIS IS WHERE THE INPUT STREAM IS DEFINED
                            inputStream = response.body().byteStream();
                            byte[] buffer = new byte[256];

                            // PRETTY MUCH while(true) ... THIS CONTINUOUSLY LISTENS FOR KEYPAD PRESSES
                            while (running) {

                                Log.v(TAG, "Reading...");

                                int bytesRead = inputStream.read(buffer, 0, buffer.length);
                                Log.v(TAG, bytesRead + " Bytes read");

                                String fullResponse = new String(buffer, 0, bytesRead, StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
                                Log.v(TAG, "Full response: " + fullResponse);

                                // I use this method to parse the json response for the key I want
                                processResponse(fullResponse);
                            }

                        } catch (IOException e) {
                            Log.v(TAG, "Exception...");

                            e.printStackTrace();

                        } finally {

                            // I TRY TO CLOSE THE INPUT STREAM HERE BUT THE PROGRAM NEVER REACHES THIS POINT.
                            try {
                                Log.v(TAG, "Closiing input stream...");

                                inputStream.close();
                                Log.v(TAG, "Success");

                            } catch (IOException e1) {
                                e1.printStackTrace();
                                Log.v(TAG, "Failure...");

                            }
                        }
                    }
                });
                keyboardInputThread.start();

            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<ResponseBody> call, Throwable t) {
            Log.d(TAG, "Response error failure: throwable=" + t);
        }
    });
}
```

My theory is that the input stream is never closed because the try block is never finished. It runs continuosly `while(true)`. I need this to be the case. So where do I close the input stream when the user clicks back? I've tried `onStop()` and `onDestroy()` but those also aren't guaranteed to be called.

Comment: @Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    // your code.
} had you tryied

Comment: Use [onPause](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities/activity-lifecycle.html#onpause) to set running to false whenever the user leaves your activity. But your read call will also be blocking while waiting for input, so you're going to have to account for that too.

Comment: @android_jain : Closing the input stream onPause causes a exception Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unbalanced enter/exit

Comment: And onBackPressed() I mean

Answer (score 0):

**Add onPause in your activity class:-**

```
 /**
  * Called as part of the activity lifecycle when an activity is going into
 * the background, but has not (yet) been killed.  The counterpart to
 * {@link #onResume}.
 *
 * <p>When activity B is launched in front of activity A, this callback will
 * be invoked on A.  B will not be created until A's {@link #onPause} returns,
 * so be sure to not do anything lengthy here.**/

    @Override
    public void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
         if (inputStream  != null) {
            try {
                inputStream .close();
            }
            catch(IOException ioex) {
                //Very bad things just happened... handle it
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: This gives me the error : java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to stop activity {com.example.testmode/com.example.testmode.TestFragments.KeypadTestActivity}: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unbalanced enter/exit